# How to check what color model the computer display is using?

Tags: display, colors

Is there a way to check whether it's using **RGB** model or **YUV** or another ?

Comment: Computer displays are RGB. Perhaps you need to be more specific?

Comment: Are all computer displays RGB? How to prove that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Computer displays are using rgb model. As you can see by looking at the signal description of the interfaces [VGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector) or [DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface). The CMYK model (subtractive color model) for example is used for Color Printers. 
It´s because of the base color. The additive model uses black asbase color (as your computer display is in default state). The subtractive model uses white as base color (as the piece of paper you want to print something onto).

Comment: But we can also watch HD video on computer,right?

Comment: yeah if your display supports the needed resolution. The color model has nothing to do with the file format.

Answer (score 4):

I have been trying to find an answer to this question for a while and so far have not found a good solution. However, I want to provide an alternative to the now incorrect "accepted" answer.

The YUV color model is the basis for the analog YPbPr and digital YCbCr color models. The differences among those 3 are subtle, technical, and in most settings not that important. A modern digital monitor or TV is going to be using either RGB or YCbCr color models and may support both. Both color models can encode the same color *space*, they just present the color information differently. In particular, the YCbCr model supports chroma sub-sampling, a powerful form of lossy compression, so it is the format of choice for video. RGB video signals are always uncompressed full resolution.

In general, computers use the RGB color model, and the DVI standard originally only supported RGB. However, Digital TVs use the YCbCr color model (analog component video uses YPbPr), and HDMI by default uses YCbCr.

HDMI was designed to be compatible with DVI at the PHY (electrical signal) level, which is why you can have a passive DVI to HDMI adapter. As a result, there is *de facto* support for DVI using the YCbCr color model and HDMI using the RGB color model.

Some displays (notably Dell's) allow you to switch the color model of the display. Dell calls the color models color formats and uses "YPbPr" (which is the analog signal version of the digital YCbCr) to refer to YCbCr, so on a Dell monitor with an HDMI input, you can usually see which color model it is using by searching through the display's menus.

As a general rule, if a computer monitor only has a DVI input, it supports RGB and probably not YCbCr. If a TV only has an HDMI input, it supports YCbCr and probably not RGB. If a monitor has a DisplayPort input, or both DVI and HDMI inputs, it probably supports both RGB and YCbCr.

I have not found a reliable way to determine via command line tools what color model the computer is using for its video output. macOS appears to prefer to use YCbCr if the monitor advertises support for it in its EDID, and in some versions indicated it was using YCbCr by labeling the monitor a Television, but I can find no indication of which color model is in use in macOS Catalina. If someone knows a way to do this, please update this answer with the details.